# TFS Explorer, how remove project in TFS Explorer Workspace

Tags: tfs

i remove a project in tfs admin console - team projects.

but i cant remove in local wordkspace, how can remove this projects which have plus icon.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try Advanced-> Remove Mapping option.

Answer (score 0):

In the **Source Controller Explorer** go to the Parent Project Collection for the deleted Project and try to Get the **Latest Version**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things.

1) right-click and select "undo pending change"
2) right-click and select "remove" 
3) open the file folder and delete the folder.

You are removing it from source (1) and then from your solution (2), before finally removing it from disk (3).